# Python script returning empty string in Bash script only when arguments supplied

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

If I have a Python script that simply prints the first argument it is given

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
try:
    print sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "No args"
```

I can run it find and get the expected output. Now if I write a Bash script that simply runs the python script and echos its output.

```
#!/bin/bash
test="Test"
echo `python test.py`
```

Then the bash script will successfully echo "No args". However if I change line 3 to

```
echo `python test.py $test`
```

Then I will simply get an empty string as the output of the Bash script and I'm not sure why. I even get the empty string when I change it to

```
echo `python test.py "test"`
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Argument is printed with both of the last two commands.

Comment: This is most strange, what about echo $(python test.py $test)

Comment: Unable to reproduce, when you run your script, use `bash -x scriptname` to get a trace of the expansions.  Try not to use backticks, `$(  )` is safer and more readable.

Comment: Before you deploy a script like that, please test it with `test='*'` and decide whether this is the desired behavior

Comment: So far we know it happens on some systems and it does not on others, so your operating system, Bash version and Python version would probably be interesting. I can't reproduce it either (Debian 7.8 with Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64, Bash 4.2.37, Python 2.7.3).

Comment: since `test` is the name of a shell builtin, perhaps you'd be better off choosing a different name for your variable and trying it again?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the backticks to $() seems to have worked

Answer (score 0):

You should try in your bash script file:

```
python test.py $test
```

It will print your $test variable content.

I call Python script without backquotes and echo. I work a lot with Bash/Python scripts combinations, and this work well for me.